# Click event code for controls keep adding new instances for themselves

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I am working on a program and have run into an odd issue I've never seen before.  I spent about 30 minutes on some code and tested, it worked fine.  I spent another 10 minutes, hit save, and tested.  Now, the button I was pressing to test has stopped working.

I went back to the code and when I double clicked the button control on the form that HAD been working fine, it had no code in it at all anymore.

I was confused obviously but then I noticed the name in the code was wrong.  So, here is the original.

```
Private Sub btnExitSearch_Click
```

And when I double clicked it to modify the code, it now shows this..

```
Private Sub btnExitSearch_Click_1
```

It added an "_1" after the control name.  I then noticed, it was doing that with EVERY control on the form.  First run: Code, test, working.  Second run: Code, test broken.

Any idea why this is happening and how to stop it?

Comment: Does the code have `AddHandler ...` lines for the buttons?  If so, the designer doesn't know the click method is already subscribed.  The designer tries to create it when you double-click it, but since the method already exists, it adds the `_1` to make it unique.

Comment: The handler must have the correct signature and the `Handles` keyword: `Private Sub btnExitSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExitSearch.Click`

Comment: It does, I just didn't paste those here.  Minus the body of the code, here is the start of the code.  


`Private Sub btnOpenFile_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)`

Comment: Is the `Handles btnExitSearch.Click` there?

Comment: So the handles section wasn't there even though I would've sworn it was previously.  

After adding the handles section, it worked.  I then tested a few more times and things seemed ok.  

However, I just went in after shutting down last night and reloaded my project.  Every single "handles" declaration is gone again.  I don't get why those keep going away.

Comment: There was [a known bug for this issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Form-Events-lost-on-compile-and-run-afte/10283572)....